# Why can't i map this array of objects within an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity, next-redux-wrapper

Hi guy's i've been working with next.js, redux and sanity.io. It's been awful... Lol

Anyways here's the code i'm stuck with

```
ServiceCards.js 

import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getNavItems } from '../redux/actions/navItems';

const ServicesCards = () => {
  const services = useSelector((state) => state.services.services);

console.log(services)

  return (
    <>
    {Object.keys(services).map((item) => {

   

return(
  <h2>{item}</h2>
)



     
  
    })}
   
    </>
  );
};
export default ServicesCards;
```

as you can see i am connecting to the redux store perfectly and the data is been retuned like:

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
0:
body: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
locations: [{…}]
mainImage: {_type: 'image', asset: {…}}
slug: {_type: 'slug', current: 'patios'}
title: "Patios"
_id: "70f4ad81-f8eb-414a-8e76-da8bf98cc4de"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {_id: 'cc9548aa-ccf5-4688-a6ac-3b1a41f9896d', body: Array(10), locations: Array(1), mainImage: {…}, slug: {…}, …}
2:
body: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
locations: [{…}]
mainImage: {_type: 'image', asset: {…}}
slug:
current: "tree-removal"
_type: "slug"
[[Prototype]]: Object
title: "Tree Removal"
_id: "f63a0092-4b89-4ea9-9e49-f618d5f5f0b9"
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
__proto__: (...)
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

So the structure of the data i am getting back is

```
{
0:{...},
1: {...},
2:{...}

}
```

Usually i just use Object.keys to map objects and i have no issues using this, so why will it not work here?

Closer look at Object.keys

```
return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(services).map((item) => {
        return <h2>{item}</h2>;
      })}
    </>
  );
```

and this is what i get back from render

```
0
1
2
```

With no data at all.

```
store.js

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import reducer from './reducers/pages';

const middleware = [thunkMiddleware];

const initialState = {
  pages: {},
  navItems: {},
  services: []
};

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

const initStore = () => {
  return store;
};

const wrapper = createWrapper(initStore, { debug: true });

export default wrapper;
```

i Have had to set initialState in next-redux-wrapper to get it to work, don't ask me why... I wish i would have stayed with Gatsby.js.

I really help someone can help with this as it's driving me crazy, i bet it's so simple!!

Comment: `Object.keys` returns an array of keys and not values. it should be something like this `{Object.keys(services).map((key) => { const item = services[key];
        return <h2>{item}</h2>;
      })}`

Comment: This worked, i love you!!!!!!

Comment: Glad it helped! Adding it as an answer so it's easy to find for others

Answer (score 2):

You may use `Object.values` instead:

```
Object.values(services).map((item) => (
  <h2>{item}</h2>
))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys` returns an array of keys and not values.
It should be something like this

```
{Object.keys(services).map((key) => { 
    const item = services[key];
    return <h2>{item}</h2>;       
})}
```